# Azure Devops - pipeline to delete single s3 file

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-pipelines, aws-cli

I would like a pipeline setup that I can run manually.  The idea here is that it deletes a single file held within an AWS S3 account.  I know technically there are many ways to do this, but what is best practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a task: AWS CLI and add it  into pipeline to delete a single file held within an AWS S3 account.
You can follow below steps :

1、  You should create a service connection before adding a AWS CLI task to pipeline.

[Create AWS service connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMyEM.png)

2、 Add AWS CLI task to pipeline and configure required parameters. Please know the meaning of parameters about AWS CLI. You can refer the document :

[Command structure in the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-commandstructure.html)

The command structure is like:

```
aws <command> <subcommand> [options and parameters]
```

In this example, you can use the command below to delete a single s3 file:

```
aws s3 rm s3://BUCKET_NAME/uploads/file_name.jpg
```

“s3://BUCKET_NAME/uploads/file_name.jpg” is the file path you saved in S3.

[AWS CLI in pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EuqA.png)

3 run the pipeline and the single s3 file can be deleted successfully.